# Update UI control frequently with multiple threads

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a DevExpress GridControl oneway binding to a tableview in the viewmodel. There are about 20 background threads querying data from databases and update the tableview individually. The update to the table view is guardard with lock for async update. Dispatcher is used for refreshing the main UI thread. I also have another button to cancel the database and update functions via CancellationTokenSource.

However, when the applicatoin runs, I have to click the cancellation button many times in order to execute code in the cancel command. In another word, the UI Main thread is busy refreshing the GridControl and it blocks the Cancel Button.

Is there a way to achive this function?

**Edit:** Found this method helps a lot *await Dispatcher.Yield(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);*
It simply gives other UI controls a chance to be executed.

> Creates an awaitable object that asynchronously yields control back to the current dispatcher and provides an opportunity for the dispatcher to process other events. (MSDN)

Comment: When the UI thread is busy, it's busy. Perhaps you could update the data bound data collection more efficiently? Perhaps just update the changes, rather than the whole collection each time?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, UI stands for User Interface, where main part is **User**! **User** is not robot, it is a person, which uses your application. You do not need to query data updates so often on UI thread. Why do you need 20 threads for database query operation? You have the single GridControl, which can show only several rows at time on the screen, 20, 50, 100 (no more). So, I suggest you to have only one thread for reading data from database, and do it once per 2-5 seconds, in order to provide **User** with some interactivity. For this purpose, [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx) - is the good choice. Using it with [CancellationToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx) - is good way to support cancellation with your scenario. Between database queries you can do the following:

```
while (true)
{
    myToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    // database query here

    myToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne(2000)
}
```

Also, before updating source collection, you can use the following:

```
GridControl.BeginDataUpdate();
//Update your source collection
GridControl.EndDataUpdate();
```

This will prevent DevExpress control from listening [CollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.collectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event, or any other, because on each Add/Remove action DevExpress call [UpdateLayout()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.updatelayout(v=vs.110).aspx) method, which is no so fast as we want to.

> if layout is invalid in either respect, the UpdateLayout call will redo the entire layout. Therefore, you should avoid calling UpdateLayout after each incremental and minor change in the element tree.

Comment: There are a lot of databases I need to query, so I query them in parallel to boost the speed. How do I call BeginDataUpdate/EndDataUpdate if I update the data in viewmodel?

Comment: You need to pass GridControl to your ViewModel, it is easy way, but you can say that it breaks yours MVVM pattern (say hello to DevExpress). Another way is to stop raising CollectionChanged and PropertyChanged event of your collection, and your collection elements, and do it only when the update cycle finished, raising Reset event (a bit annoying, but your MVVM-ism will be satisfied). Also you have more other options to save loose coupled V and VM, but this is another quiestion

Comment: true, what is this for "while (myToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne(2000))"

Comment: yes, my mistake. One moment - and you will see the edit.

Comment: yes, thanks for the suggestion, but do we need to block the thread for 2 seconds?

Comment: You can choose interval you want, but it should not be less then 0.5 seconds. It will be enough for interactivity, and your databases will not be overloaded by lots of queries.